# What does assert equal to empty parentheses (assert x == ()) mean?

Tags: python, numpy, assert

Trying to figure out the meaning of the following assertion statement  but no sure whether it's an assertion thing or a numpy notation:

If `cost` is an `np.array`, what does this assertion mean?

```
assert(cost.shape == ())
```

Comment: ...That the `shape` attribute results in an empty tuple...

Comment: Also, the outer parentheses are redundant, and therefore bad style. `assert cost.shape == ()`

Comment: ...also slightly hazardous because if you write `assert(cost.shape == (), 'shape should be scalar')`, it will always be true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`()` is an empty tuple, this assert checks if the shape of `cost` is an empty tuple. So it checks if `cost` is a scalar.

Comment: Note that `np.array(3.14159).shape == ()`, i.e. scalars have no dimensions.